# Sci-fi trilogy from about 30 years ago, alien artifacts hidden inside 3 humans

Tags: story-identification, books

So this is what I remember:

- It was about some alien artifacts or something that had been hidden inside 3 humans, which the aliens were trying to get back
- I only read the first book, but it started with a car chase in France and specifically mentioned driving like Damon Hill so I suspect a British author. There was a car crash and I think the boys' parents died
- I think I read it about 1995 (which also backs up the Hill reference)
- I think the first book ends with on a spaceship

I’ve been thinking about this book series ever since, am hoping now I can solve the mystery!